# Restrict system files access to the public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ruby on Rails 3.2
My application has images stored in:

```
http://name.name.com/system/images/imgs/xxx/xxx/xxx/thumb/xxx.jpg?xxxxxxxxx
```

I noticed that you can get access to the files when not logged in. I tried doing a before_filter in my controller but when I look at the log there is no query, and it is not using the controller.

How do you restrict access to system files to only users that are on my website and logged in? Thank you,

Comment: Move your files out of the `public` folder, and then use a controller action with `send_file` to serve the files to only authenticated users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the files from the $RAILS_ROOT/public folder and move them somewhere else, e.g. $SHARED_FOLDER/uploads/.

Then create routes that point to a controller:

```
class FilesController
  def show
    # first check credentials
    path = ... # use params to look up the path, but be careful to check the
               # validity!
               # It's probably best to have an index that contains valid files
               # and to only return those. Otherwise an attacker might be able
               # to compromise your server and your data.
    send_file path
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems there should be a simple solution. If I only move some files from my database to a different directory the scalability and management would get old real quick. Most of my files I want to be public. Isn't there something I can do to the database management?